# How to get with in array values in ng-options using of angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

I am trying to get the values as a drop down or select field which were with in the `comments` array. I am trying for `comments` array of `commentText` value in the `drop down`, how can i do this in the `ng-option` ?. [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eVOh7GiWMKaH1D86pUqP?p=preview)

For Example:

I did the drop down `ng-option` for first without array value. Now i am looking for comments array value of[commentText": "7A"] in the drop down how can i do that.

I tried `ng-options="item.comments.commentText for item in questions"` it's not working for me. How to fix it?

My Data:

```
    $scope.questions = [
{
"_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
"user": {
"_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 1,
"comments": [
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "7A"
}
],
"questionid": "",
"created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
}
]
```

My Html:

```
    <label>1. Without array value</label>
  <select ng-model="class"  ng-options="item.title for item in questions">
  </select>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
  <label>2. With comments array value</label>
  <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class"  ng-options="item.comments.commentText for item in questions">
  </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Will this do it `ng-options="element.commentText for element in class.comments"` ? `class` comes from ng-model of your selected question. Otherwise you need to [flatten](http://jsfiddle.net/27UGZ/2/) your double array

Comment: thanks for your comment if possible can you update my plunker as well...

Comment: Just change your second select to `<select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class2"  ng-options="element.commentText for element in class.comments">`. Make sure your ng-models are different

Comment: I have updated  my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ultpnNcFbIdFXur4XJU3?p=preview with your answer, it's not working for me so please check and update, i don't know where i did the mistake

Comment: I meant that you select a question first (that's what the first select is for) and then you select a comment from a list of comments for that question. You have a nested array after all. If you want all of the comments for all questions, then you need to flatten your arrays first, I gave you a link with an example earlier

Comment: I have tried your answer it's shows perfectly in dropdown and if I used your answer in my project `section` comment saved as a `true or false` I just want to save section like `7A or 8A`  is there any ideas?...

Comment: Show an updated plunker with maybe more explanations

Comment: Please look this updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/RdlwZYuKjpe6txV2TUKW?p=preview, In plunker it's working fine but while implementing this into my project getting following error `
Cast to String failed for value "[object Object]" at path "school_section_change"` i don't know what to do...please help us thanks...

Comment: `school_section_change` is not used in your example, so I can't help you with that, I assume you are using **mongoose** somewhere and one of your schemas is wrong - default value is string, not object

Answer (score 0):

Edit : 
That's what i edit : 
I merge all comments of all questions to one array, and added question id to each comment (like that we can filter using question (ng-model of first select))
I hope it helps

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div>
      <label>1. Without array value</label>
      <select ng-model="question" ng-options="item.title for item in questions">
      </select>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
     <label>2. With comments array value</label>
     <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class" ng-options="item.commentText for item in filteredComments()">
     </select>
    </div>
```

He Script of Controllers ( question_id changed in comments to get a pratical example)

```
$scope.comments = [];
  $scope.question = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(item) {
    angular.forEach(item.comments, function(comment) {
      comment.question_id = item._id;
      $scope.comments.push(comment);
    });
  });

  $scope.filteredComments = function() {
    if ($scope.question._id) {
      var filteredComments = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.comments, function(item) {
        if (item.question_id == $scope.question._id) {
          this.push(item);
        }
      }, filteredComments);

      return filteredComments;
    } else {
      return $scope.comments
    };
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UzP9fnsxxPfngVRAW0c0?p=preview

Comment: I dont know what is your goal but i think you want to make second select (comments) depends of first one (question) ? if its that so the answer is not the good one. You're welcome

Comment: Hi Amenz your answer is not working for me, so check and update, actually we have two school and two comments [section] like 7A and 8A but your answer drop down showing only one section like 7A so plaese check and plunker as well to know the exact answer...

Comment: It's previsible because the second select is only repeat only first question comments!  can you asnwer thoses questions before update:
- do you want all comments listed ?
- do you want if we select question , comments select filter only this question's comments?

Comment: Yes exactly second is right , I just want  if we select question, comments select filter only this question's comments...thanks for helping please update plunker.....

Comment: Hi Amenz this is my html code `<div> <select  id="school_section_change" name="school_section_change" ng-model="vm.school_section_change"  ng-options="item.commentText for item in vm.filteredComments()"></select></div>`your answer is not working for me bcoz what's my problem is you where used `$scope` in `script.js` but I am using `vm` in my code so please check `my ng-module` and if possible please edit your answer using of $scope instead of `vm` thanks.....

Comment: Hi, please update your plunker with what you tried now and iwill check!
But normally if you are using vm ( Alias) in controllers ( var vm = this;) you replace all your variables in controllers $scope.myvar becomes vm.myvar.

Comment: Hi Amenz I am looking like similar answer pls check this:- stackoverflow.com/questions/47434475/… please help us thanks